# How to retrieve the column with mandatory decimal point in Sql 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, decimal

I am retrieving a numeric value from one of the column in Sql. However I have to retrieve it by three decimal point (eg below).

Though if the value in the table is in the decimal point, then its giving the result as expected. But in case the value is not in decimal format and only an integer it must display .000 
Below is the example.

```
Value in table= 2
Retrieval Value = 2
Required Value = 2.000
```

Comment: Try to do that formatting in the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To really show a value in a particular format, you can convert the value to a string.  One method uses the [`str()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function:

```
str(x, 18, 3)
```

Note that you can also `cast()` the decimal:

```
select cast(cast(x as decimal(18, 3)) as varchar(19))
```

Comment: Very much thanks. Exactly what I was looking for. Both of your answer works perfectly. Thanks Again

Answer (score 2):

As per your requirement convert your incoming value in `Decimal(18,3)`. like given below,

```
select convert(decimal(18,3),2)
```

Comment: Didn't worked. I am getting only 2 in result. I require 2.000